# Storing a list to a string from an arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to display all the String content from an `ArrayList` but the size of the `ArrayList` is unknown (using Android Studio).
So for example:

```java
fruit = new ArrayList<>()
veg = new ArrayList<>()
```

After some operations, now the story `ArrayList` contained some information, such as:

```java
fruit = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "peach",...};
veg = {"cucumber", "spinach", "pumpkin", "broccoli",...};
```

I do not know how long the `ArrayList` of fruit and veg are after the operations. But I know that the fruit and veg has the same size of `ArrayList`. I want to store each of the list to be like:

```java
fruitOne = fruit(0), fruitTwo = fruit(1), fruitThree = fruit(2),...
vegOne = veg(0), vegTwo = veg(1), vegThree = veg(2),...
```

Then I want to display them together as a String so that I can have a string such as:

```java
String myStore = "I am selling" + fruitOne + " and " + vegOne + "/n" + fruitTwo + " and " + vegTwo + "/n" + fruitThree + " and " + vegThree"...;
```

I feel like it needs to use `for` loops to pull each of the list one by one by calling `fruit(0), fruit(1),...,fruit(i)`. But how do I store each of this list of `fruit(0), fruit(1),...,fruit(i)` independently so that I can concatenate them together to become one String of myStore?

All the tutorial kept on taking about `println` or `logd`, so it can print the `fruit(i)` or `veg(i)` each for loop, but not really storing the `fruit(i)` or `veg(i)` as a variable to be used independently.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can also use LinkedHashMap if you want to store these as a variable. Use fruits as key and veg as value. It'll give you more control.

Comment: but I still don't know how many fruits and veg that went inside my map. And later when I want to call it, I think I still need to use for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `StringBuilder` to build the string.

Since both lists have the same number of elements, use a simple `for` loop to iterate both lists.

```java
List<String> fruit = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange", "banana", "peach");
List<String> veg = Arrays.asList("cucumber", "spinach", "pumpkin", "broccoli");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("I am selling ");
int count = fruit.size();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append(fruit.get(i));
    sb.append(" and ");
    sb.append(veg.get(i));
    sb.append("\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Running the above code produces the following string:

```
I am selling apple and cucumber
orange and spinach
banana and pumpkin
peach and broccoli
```

Comment: Hi, I have a question. I tried it, and it works. But the problem now is that if I run the code twice, the String appended from the "for loop" also doubles. So it will says that I am selling apple and cucumber, orange and spinach, banana and pumpkin, peach and broccoli, apple and cucumber, orange and spinach, banana and pumpkin, peach and broccoli. I tried to put sb.setLength(0) after the println(sb). But it does not do anything.

Comment: I checked with logd that before the "for loop", the sb is cleared out (either because the code runs the new StringBuilder() again, or because I set sb.setLength(0) at the very end. But the code remember what it appends by the "for loop" from the previous run. The sb.setLength(0) does clear out the sb (including the info from "for loop"), but when it runs through the "for loop" the second times, it pulls the info from the previous run of "for loop" too. I would really appreciate your help, thank you!